# Получение индекса элемента массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть переменная `int a=5`, которой инициализируем элемент массива `int b[3]={a,2,3}`, потом получаем переменную `int a1=5`. Имея а1 нужно узнать равна ли она элементу массива, и если равна то, самое важное — получить индекс.
Так вот, проблема в том, что это надо сделать не используя цикл. В .NET есть `Array::IndexOf(Array^, Object^)`, есть ли аналог в C++? Может шаблонные классы?

Comment: Если и есть такой метод - то он все равно использует цикл.

Comment: Дак ведь у вас неупорядоченный массив, каким еще образом можно найти в нем искомый элемент (или вы чего-то недоговариваете)?

Comment: Ну возможно, он написан на ассемблере, что даст прирост производительности. А вообще мне кажется, что есть способ нахождения через адреса

Comment: Глупости. Если подумать, можно доказать, что меньше O(N) не получить

Comment: @StateItPrimitive а он и не должен быть упорядоченным, он заполняется в течении выполнения программы . Это важно?

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик да, важно, иначе (если бы он был упорядоченный), можно за O(logN) найти (бинарный поиск)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: @АлексейСаровский,  а можно поподробней? Ведь, в принципе, я и походу выполнения смогу его упорядочить.

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик упорядочить - это минимум O(NlogN). Можно целиком текст задачи увидеть?

Comment: @SkiesX я ж писал, что знаю о таком аналоге. Я не хочу использовать .NET

Comment: @АлексейСаровский целиком вряд ли влезет.У меня в WndProc приходит HWND, надо как-то различать. Создал массив дескрипторов, и при каждом вызове WndProc сравниваю HWND с элементами массива(с помощи цикла). Представьте, что происходит при WM_PAINT (в массиве 200 элементов)-_-

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик Но если вы его упорядочите ради того, чтобы всего лишь 1 раз выполнять поиск всего лишь одного элеента, то в этом вообще не будет смысла, т.к. общая сложность (упорядочить + найти) будет даже выше чем O(N). Но вот если вы после упорядочивания будете искать многократно различные элементы в массие, то совсем другое дело.

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик я вас не понял сейчас. Просил текст ЗАДАЧИ. Или вы ее сами себе поставили?

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик единственное, что могу предложить: Если эту задачу надо выполнять часто на одном и том же массиве (поиск то есть), то сделайте вектор-индикатор этого массива и потом поиск будет занимать O(1)

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик  Сам себе поставил

Comment: Скорее всего для такой задачи подойдет [unordered set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) или другая реализация хэш-таблиц.

Comment: @avp , для WM_PAINT?

Comment: А что такое `WM_PAINT`? Наверняка по сути или адрес, или индекс в какой-то таблице системных дескрипторов (т.е. число 32 или 64-bit)

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик  там синтаксис есть и для С++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предисловие: в комментариях с автором выяснили, зачем ему это, прикладываю ответ

Так как обращение будет частое к массиву, то удобно применить вектор-индикатор. Ограничиваем максимальное значение в массиве `MAX_VALUE` и создаем `int`-массив размера `MAX_VALUE`. На начальном этапе ОДИН РАЗ инициализируем его примерно так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)// count - размер массива
   vector[hwnd[i]] = i;
```

Теперь чтобы узнать индекс элемента, достаточно обратиться к `vector[i]` - это и будет его индекс в массиве `hwnd`. Если нужно добавить/удалить значения в hwnd, то соответствующим образом поменять vector

Comment: Так, хорошо, `vector` - `int` массив, правильно понял?

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик да. Можно проинициализировать -1

Comment: То есть я в `vector` передаю hwnd, который у меня в WM_PAINT пришёл. Но HWND это ж не `int`... То есть нормально если его в качестве индекса передать?

Comment: Ох, меня терзают смутные сомнения, что MAX_VALUE либо нельзя будет заранее указать, либо оно будет такой величиной, что... Какой там вообще размер массива? стоит ли того, чтоб заморачиваться? Если это, грубо говоря, сотня - то там поиск будет почти мгновенный, нет?

Comment: @Harry 200 элементов но всё равно долго ишёт. Да МАКС_ВЭЛУЭ нельзя задать, как размер массива

Comment: Так ведь тут `std::map` в самый раз будет.

Comment: @alexolut , но ведь там тоже придётся цикл использовать для переборки, или я не так понял `map` ?

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик Вообще да. Хотя map и отсортирован по ключам, но искать-то как-то надо (минимум O(logN)). Можно посмотреть в принципе в сторону unordered_map - хэш-функция прирост должна хороший давать

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, я немного подчитал, делаю так : объявление - `map<HWND,int>m`, инициализация -  `m[hwnd]=1`, а для получения индеска - `m[hwnd]`. Вроде ж без цикла. Или это неправильно?

Comment: @АлесандрВогрик это вы цикл не делаете, но на самом деле он есть (в операторе [])

Answer (score 1):

Не используя цикл, можно использовать алгоритм `find` из STL (`find_if` в данном случае - перебор).

Есть и второй способ без применения циклов - применить рекурсию.

Но вы уверены, что вам нужно именно это? :)

Если вопрос в производительности - то быстрее цикла все равно ничего не будет, O(N) для неупорядоченного массива никак не переплюнуть.

Другое дело, что хранить эти значения можно не в массиве, а в том же `unordered_set` и получить свое за `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, решение найдено. Наиболее удачный вариант - `std::map` . Возможно он не изменяет О(N), однако, конкретно в моём случае он повысил производительность. Ещё хороший вариант - `for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)// count - размер массива
   vector[hwnd[i]] = i;` , но я не много не понял как задавать индекс через HWND. `reinterpret_cast` помог, но с ним были другие заморочки. Ещё раз всем спасибо